What happened to this meme coin?
How something like this shown in the chart can happen and how can I possibly find out before it happens.
https://dexscreener.com/solana/2wicz7qpvun1rnuhvusdf8xah22rbkixekgs43rdboj4

They freeze your token account and you can't sell your tokes.
Just don't buy it, if you see chart like this)
